# Authenticate Sharepoint users using digital certificates

Tags: authentication

We have internet facing Sharepoint 2007?

We have recently distributed digital certificates to our users, mainly for authentication purposes.

We would like to enable users to authenticate to MOSS using only certificates.

How would one approach building custom authentication module that would authenticate users and map them to their corresponding windows accounts?

Answer (score 2):

If your certs map to AD accounts, then Moss 2007 can natively support them based on underlying support for cert auth/mapping in IIS. For alternative credential mapping or two-factor, you either need to front SharePoint with something like Forefront UAG or write a custom forms-based identity provider. Example here - http://goo.gl/XuMju

Answer (score 2):

As your certificates map to AD accounts, you take client certificates in use with MOSS with the following steps:

1. Select Windows authentication in Central Administration.
2. Configure IIS for certificate authentication.
3. Enable Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).
4. Obtain and configure certificates from a certification authority (CA).

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288475%28office.12%29.aspx)